# returning table name with columns when queried

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running some queries that have joins in them. The tables are large and have some columns with identical names. Is there a way I can create a query that'll prefix the table name with the column name?

I'd like something like...

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON u.id = f.userID
```

And have it display something along the lines of....

```
u.id | u.name | u.email ... f.id | f.name ...
```

Instead of just

```
id | name | email ... id | name ...
```

I like to process my queries as associative arrays because they're easy to read as opposed to numbered indexes, so this makes things challenging when the column names aren't unique.

Comment: I have replaced `*` with a listing of columns with aliases - `u.id u_id, f.id f_id` and so forth. If someone has a more automatic approach, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Most of the time, it's considered best practice to specify your columns, as to avoid indexing and binding problems. Furthermore it's more efficient.

Comment: The only problem with that, and I agree, most of the time that's how I prefer to do them, but these are tables with 50+ fields each, so taking the time to put each column name in there can be tedious.

Comment: What happens with `SELECT u.*, f.* FROM ...`? And what's the client language?

Comment: same results, just lists the column name without the indicator. I had the same thought though

Comment: This is where I tend to copy and paste from `\d` to vim and let loose the regexp replaces.

Comment: I just broke down and did add the identifiers for each column. this has gotten a lot of attention, but no answers so I'm guessing that's not a feature that can be used yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alias your columns -- (and if you want the period in the column name, you need to use double quotes):

```
select u.id as "u.id", 
       u.name as "u.name",
       u.email as "u.email",
       f.id as "f.id",
       f.name as "f.name"
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN favorites f ON u.id = f.userID
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it does not seem that it's possible to do it any other way beyond manually assigning field names for each individual field you want returned.